# javascript in classic asp script block within script block error

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm trying to add the following

```
<div class="pubble-app PQAQ_section" data-app-id="43522"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.pubble.io/javascript/loader.js" defer></script>
```

I'm using classic asp. But the error I keep getting is "A script block cannot be placed inside another script block." I tried the document.write technique found here: [Javascript code in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108765/javascript-code-in-classic-asp), but no go.

The loader.js code:

```
    var pbsafaridialogWindow,safariwindow_poll,ttt,initModuleTest;var pubbleLoader={};var pbldv="170828001";if(!String.prototype.trim){String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,"")}}if(!String.prototype.len){String.prototype.len=function(){return this.trim().replace(/[^\x00-\xff]/g,"**").length}}if(!String.prototype.startsWith){String.prototype.startsWith=function(substring){var reg=new RegExp("^"+substring);return reg.test(this)}}if(!String.prototype.replaceAll){String.prototype.replaceAll=function(reallyDo,replaceWith,ignoreCase){if(!RegExp.prototype.isPrototypeOf(reallyDo)){return this.replace(new RegExp(reallyDo,(ignoreCase?"gi":"g")),replaceWith)}else{return this.replace(reallyDo,replaceWith)}}}if(typeof(window.pubbleLoader_init)==="undefined"){var pubbleLoader=(function(args){if(typeof(args)!=="undefined"){alert("args");initModule.loadConfig(args)}var initModule={removeParameter:function(url,parameter){var urlparts=url.split("?");if(urlparts.length>=2){var urlBase=urlparts.shift();var queryString=urlparts.join("?");var prefix=encodeURIComponent(parameter)+"=";var pars=queryString.split(/[&;]/g);for(var i=pars.length;i-->0;){if(pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix,0)!==-1){pars.splice(i,1)}}url=urlBase+"?"+pars.join("&")}return url},filterPubbleParas:function(url){url=this.removeParameter(url,"PPMID");url=this.removeParameter(url,"PPMID");url=this.removeParameter(url,"visitor");url=this.removeParameter(url,"PPBUID");url=this.removeParameter(url,"PPBLINK");url=this.removeParameter(url,"myenquiry");url=this.removeParameter(url,"PPBUT");url=this.removeParameter(url,"PPBCID");url=url.replace("#myenquiry","");url=url.replace(/\?\s*$/,"");return url},initParams:function(){var data={callback:"pubbleLoader.initLoader"};for(var v in pubbleLoader.init){if(pubbleLoader.init.hasOwnProperty(v)){switch(v){default:if(typeof pubbleLoader.init[v]!=="undefined"&&pubbleLoader.init[v]!==null){data[v]=pubbleLoader.init[v]}break}}}initModule.initParams=function(){return data};return data},encode:function(a){return escape(this._utf8_encode(a))},decode:function(a){return this._utf8_decode(unescape(a))},_utf8_encode:function(b){b=b.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var a="";for(var e=0;e<b.length;e++){var d=b.charCodeAt(e);if(d<128){a+=String.fromCharCode(d)}else{if((d>127)&&(d<2048)){a+=String.fromCharCode((d>>6)|192);a+=String.fromCharCode((d&63)|128)}else{a+=String.fromCharCode((d>>12)|224);a+=String.fromCharCode(((d>>6)&63)|128);a+=String.fromCharCode((d&63)|128)}}}return a},_utf8_decode:function(a){var b="";var d=0;var e=c1=c2=0;while(d<a.length){e=a.charCodeAt(d);if(e<128){b+=String.fromCharCode(e);d++}else{if((e>191)&&(e<224)){c2=a.charCodeAt(d+1);b+=String.fromCharCode(((e&31)<<6)|(c2&63));d+=2}else{c2=a.charCodeAt(d+1);c3=a.charCodeAt(d+2);b+=String.fromCharCode(((e&15)<<12)|((c2&63)<<6)|(c3&63));d+=3}}}return b}};initModule.checkSafariWindow=function(){try{if(pbsafaridialogWindow!=null&&pbsafaridialogWindow.closed){pbsafaridialogWindow=null;clearInterval(safariwindow_poll);var initPath=pubbleLoader.servers.actionDomain+"/api/init.htm";DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(initPath+"?v="+new Date().getTime()+"&"+pubbleLoader.utils.String.toParams(initModule.initParams()),"UTF-8")}}catch(exception){}},initModule.init=function(divs){for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){var div=divs[i];var PBAppID=pubbleLoader.utils.getQueryString("PBAppID");var PBID=pubbleLoader.utils.getQueryString("PBID");if(PBAppID){div.setAttribute("data-app-id",PBAppID)}if(PBID){div.setAttribute("data-app-identifier",PBID)}var id=div.getAttribute("data-app-id");var identifier=div.getAttribute("data-app-identifier");var assignAppIds=div.getAttribute("assignAppIds");var assignAccountIds=div.getAttribute("assignAccountIds");var layout=div.getAttribute("data-app-layout");var token=div.getAttribute("data-app-token");var conver_id=div.getAttribute("data-app-conversation-id");var autho_info=div.getAttribute("data-app-auth_info");var signout=div.getAttribute("data-app-signout");if(!layout){layout="embed"}if(id=="37667"||id=="37631"){initModule.loadLink(pubbleLoader.servers.actionDomain+"/resources/LQA/css/LQA_style_skeleton.css");div.className+=" PQAT_skin_skeleton"}div.setAttribute("id","pubble_app_"+id);var initData={};if(assignAppIds){initData.assignAppIds=assignAppIds}if(assignAccountIds){initData.assignAccountIds=assignAccountIds}if(signout&&signout!==undefined){initData.signOut=signOut}if(autho_info&&auth_info!==undefined){initData.autho_info=auth_info}initData.appID=id;if(identifier!==undefined&&identifier!=null&&identifier!=""){initData.identifier=identifier}initData.layout=layout;initData.callback="pubbleLoader.initLoader";initData.url=initModule.encode(initModule.filterPubbleParas(window.location.href.split("#")[0]));if(token!=undefined&&token!=null){initData.userToken=encodeURIComponent(token);if(conver_id!=undefined&&conver_id!=null){initData.conversationId=conver_id}initData.is_conversation_app=1}var initPath=pubbleLoader.servers.actionDomain+"/api/init.htm";
DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(initPath+"?v="+new Date().getTime()+"&"+pubbleLoader.utils.String.toParams(initData),"UTF-8")}};initModule.loadScript=function(d,g){var f=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];if(!f){f=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]}var h,e,c=document.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src=d;if(g){c.async=true}for(e=0;e<f.childNodes.length;e++){if(f.childNodes[e].tagName=="link"){h=f.childNodes[e]}}if(!h){f.appendChild(c)}else{a.insertSiblingAfter(c,h)}};initModule.insertSiblingAfter=function(c,d){if(d.nextSibling===undefined){d.parentNode.appendChild(c)}else{d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d.nextSibling)}},initModule.loadLink=function(c){var f=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],g,e,d=document.createElement("link");if(!f){f=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]}d.rel="stylesheet";d.type="text/css";d.href=c;d.data="pubble";d.media="all";var att=document.createAttribute("data");att.value="pb";d.setAttributeNode(att);for(e=0;e<f.childNodes.length;e++){if(f.childNodes[e].tagName=="link"){g=f.childNodes[e]}}if(!g){f.appendChild(d)}else{f.appendChild(d)}};if(window.pubbleApp_config){pubbleLoader=function(pubbleApp_config){if(typeof(pubbleApp_config)!=="undefined"){initModule.nfig(pubbleApp_config)}initModule.init();return pubbleLoader}}else{var divs=getElementsByClassName("pubble-app");pubbleLoader=function(args){initModule.init(divs);return pubbleLoader}}pubbleLoader.inject=function(src,type){type=type||"js";if(type=="js"){var s=document.createElement("script");c;s.type="text/javascript";s.async=true;s.src=src}else{if(type=="css"){var s=document.createElement("link");s.type="text/css";s.rel="stylesheet";s.href=src}}(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(s)};pubbleLoader.onInitialize=[];pubbleLoader.init={};pubbleLoader.config={};pubbleLoader.data={};pubbleLoader.libs=[];pubbleLoader.apps=[];pubbleLoader.servers={web:"",actionDomain:"http://www.pubble.io",mediaDomain:"http://media.pubble.io",cdnDomain:"https://d2dfzm19238yrf.cloudfront.net"};pubbleLoader.servers.actionDomain=("https:"==document.location.protocol)?"https://www.pubble.io":"http://www.pubble.io";pubbleLoader.servers.mediaDomain=("https:"==document.location.protocol)?"https://media.pubble.io":"http://media.pubble.io";pubbleLoader.initLoader=function(c){if(c.status=="true"||c.code=="200"){var obj=document.getElementById("pubble_app_"+c.parameters.appId);var token=obj.getAttribute("data-app-token");if(c.appType=="qa"||c.appType=="BL"||c.appType=="LQ"){var locale=c.locale;var obj=document.getElementById("pubble_app_"+c.parameters.appId);var token=obj.getAttribute("data-app-token");var l2=obj.getAttribute("data-app-locale");if(l2!=undefined&&l2!=null){locale=l2}if(locale!=""&&locale!="en"){DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask("https://www.pubble.io/resources/i18n/qa-"+locale+".js","utf-8")}}if(token!=undefined&&token!=null){initModule.loadLink("//www.pubble.io/resources/Pubble-App-CORE/css/pubble-core.css");var pusherLib=("https:"==document.location.protocol)?"https://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js":"http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js";DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(pusherLib,"utf-8");var script_url=c.scriptURL;DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(script_url,"UTF-8");c.strings={};c.appType="qac";pubbleLoader.apps.push(c)}else{if(c.appType=="CN"){var script_url=c.scriptURL;var pusherLib=("https:"==document.location.protocol)?"https://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js":"http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js";DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(pusherLib,"utf-8");DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(script_url,"UTF-8");initModule.loadLink("https://d5p15xwlzsa76.cloudfront.net/pubblebot/cw/css/pubble-cw.css");initModule.loadLink("https://d5p15xwlzsa76.cloudfront.net/pubblebot/cw/css/normalize.css");initModule.loadLink("https://d5p15xwlzsa76.cloudfront.net/pubblebot/sb/css/pubble-sb.css");pubbleLoader.apps.push(c)}else{if(c.appType=="qa"||c.appType=="BL"||c.appType=="LQ"){var obj=document.getElementById("pubble_app_"+c.parameters.appId);if(obj==null){return false}if(obj.offsetWidth>600&&c.layout!=="modalbox"&&pubbleLoader.utils.checkMetaView()){c.showOnIpad=1}if(c.SSoenabled){c.showOnIpad=1}c.showPresense=1;if(c.scriptURL.indexOf("lib4")!==-1){c.qav3=true}else{c.qav3=false}if(c.scriptURL.indexOf("core")!==-1){c.qav4=true}else{c.qav4=false}var pURL=pubbleLoader.utils.getQueryString("PBURL");var PBID=pubbleLoader.utils.getQueryString("PBID");var PBLayout=pubbleLoader.utils.getQueryString("PBLayout");var PBAppID=pubbleLoader.utils.getQueryString("PBAppID");var PPMID=0;var reg=new RegExp("PPMID(\\d+)","i");if(reg.test(window.location.href)){PPMID=RegExp.$1}c.selfhost=0;if(pURL){c.pageURL=pURL;c.selfhost=1}if(PBID){c.identifier=PBID}else{if(c.page!=null&&c.page.identifier!==""){pubbleLoader.config.identifier=c.page.identifier;c.identifier=pubbleLoader.config.identifier}else{pubbleLoader.config.identifier=c.parameters.appId;c.identifier=pubbleLoader.config.identifier}}if(PBLayout){c.layout=PBLayout}if(PBAppID){c.appID=PBAppID
}if(PPMID){c.PPMID=PPMID}var tmpl="";if(c.qav4){initModule.loadLink("//www.pubble.io/resources/Pubble-App-CORE/css/pubble-core.css");tmpl='<div style="height:50px; width:100%;"><div style="width:31px;height:31px;margin-top:9px;margin-left:50%;padding-left:-15px;"><img src="//www.pubble.io/resources/Pubble-App-CORE/img/loading.gif" alt="Pubble loading" border="0" width="31" height="31"></div></div>'}else{if(pubbleLoader.utils.isMobile()&&!c.showOnIpad){if(!pubbleLoader.utils.getQueryString("PBID")){if(!c.qav3){tmpl='<div class="PQAQ_wrapper PQAQ_wrapper_color" id="pbwidgetcontainer"><img style="width:31px !important; height:31px !important" id="loadingimg" '+'src="'+pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+'/images/app/qa/loading31.gif"></div><div id="PQAQ_customcss" '+'class="PQAQ_customcss"><style>.pb_highlight{opacity:0.5}</style></div><div id="PQAQ_social" class="PQAQ_social"></div>'+'<div id="PQAQ_debug" class="PQAQ_debug"></div>'}else{tmpl='<div class="PQAQ_modal_all PQAQ_off"><div class="PQAQ_modal"><div class="PQAQ_modal_close"></div> <div class="PQAQ_modal_header"></div><div class="PQAQ_modal_content"> </div></div></div> <div class="PQAQ_wrapper PQAQ_wrapper_color" id="pbwidgetcontainer"><img style="width:31px !important; height:31px !important" id="loadingimg" '+'src="'+pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+'/images/app/qa/loading31.gif"></div><div id="PQAQ_customcss" '+'class="PQAQ_customcss"><style>.pb_highlight{opacity:0.5}</style></div><div id="PQAQ_social" class="PQAQ_social"></div>'+'<div id="PQAQ_debug" class="PQAQ_debug"></div>'}c.showPresense=0}else{if(!c.qav3){if(c.selfhost){tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_holder PQAQ_hide scrollable" style="display:none">'}else{tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_holder scrollable" style="display:none">'}c.showPresense=1;tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_header">';tmpl+='   <div class="PQAX_header_menu">';tmpl+='        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="PQAX_btn_u"></a>';tmpl+='         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="PQAX_btn_i"></a>';tmpl+='         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="PQAX_btn_x"></a>';tmpl+="    </div>";tmpl+="    ";tmpl+='    <div class="PQAX_header_text">';tmpl+='           <div class="PQAX_title"></div>';tmpl+="     </div>";tmpl+="     ";tmpl+="</div>";tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_user PQAQ_hide">';tmpl+='   <div class="PQAX_photo"> <img/> </div>';tmpl+='    <div class="PQAX_name"></div>';tmpl+='    <div class="PQAX_status"></div>';tmpl+='    <div class="PQAX_service">';tmpl+="        ";tmpl+="    </div>";tmpl+='    <div class="PQAX_btn_logout"></div>';tmpl+='     <div class="PQAX_btn_login PQAT_hide"></div>';tmpl+='    <!-- <div class="PQAX_btn_close"></div> -->';tmpl+="</div>";tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_heart PQAQ_hide">';tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_followers"><span id="PQAX_follower_lists"><ul id="PQAX_follower_lists_ul"></ul></span>';tmpl+='             <div class="PQAX_status_text">';tmpl+='                                    <span id="PQAX_status_nrq"></span>';tmpl+='                <span id="PQAX_status_qtext"></span><br />';tmpl+='                <span id="PQAX_status_nrf"></span>';tmpl+='                <span id="PQAX_status_ftext"></span>';tmpl+="              </div>";tmpl+='        </div><div class="PQAQ_clear" style="margin-bottom:5px"></div>';tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_moderators"><span id="PQAX_mod_lists"></span><div class="PQAX_moderators_text"></div>';tmpl+='           <!-- <div class="PQAX_btn_close">HIDE</div> -->';tmpl+="</div>";tmpl+="</div>";tmpl+='<div class="PQAX_content">';tmpl+='<div class="PQAQ_wrapper PQAQ_wrapper_color" id="pbwidgetcontainer"><img style="width:31px !important" id="loadingimg" '+'src="'+pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+'/images/app/qa/loading31.gif"></div>';tmpl+="</div>";tmpl+='<div id="PQAQ_social" class="PQAQ_social" style="display:none"></div></div> '}else{tmpl='<div class="PQAQ_modal_all PQAQ_off"><div class="PQAQ_modal"><div class="PQAQ_modal_close"></div> <div class="PQAQ_modal_header"></div><div class="PQAQ_modal_content">  </div></div></div> <div class="PQAQ_wrapper PQAQ_wrapper_color" id="pbwidgetcontainer"><img style="width:31px !important; height:31px !important" id="loadingimg" '+'src="'+pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+'/images/app/qa/loading31.gif"></div><div id="PQAQ_customcss" '+'class="PQAQ_customcss"><style>.pb_highlight{opacity:0.5}</style></div><div id="PQAQ_social" class="PQAQ_social"></div>'+'<div id="PQAQ_debug" class="PQAQ_debug"></div>'}}}else{if(c.layout=="modalbox"){tmpl='<div class="PQAQ_modalbox" style="display:none"><div class="PQAM_outer_window" style="display:none">'+'<div class="PQAM_window"><div class="PQAM_header"><a class="PQAM_close" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>      '+'             <div class="PQAQ_status"><div class="PQAQ_btn_i PQAQ_hide"></div><div class="PQAQ_status_content PQAQ_hide">'+'<div class="PQAQ_status_title_u">     </div><div class="PQAQ_moderators"><span id="PQAQ_mod_lists">'+'</span><div class="PQAQ_moderators_text"></div></div><div class="PQAQ_followers"><span id="PQAQ_follower_lists">'+'</span><div class="PQAQ_status_text"></div><div class="PQAQ_status_nr"><div id="PQAQ_status_nrq"></div>'+'<div id="PQAQ_status_nrf"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="PQAQ_status_u"><div class="PQAQ_btn_u"></div>'+'<div class="PQAQ_status_content PQAQ_hide"><div class="PQAQ_status_title ">  </div><div class="PQAQ_userstatus">'+'<input class="PQAQ_userstatus_button" name="" type="button" value="" /> <div class="PQAQ_userstatus_text">   '+' </div> </div></div></div>            <div class="PQAM_title" id="PQAQ_title_mb"></div></div><div class="PQAM_middle">   '+'  <div class="PQAQ_wrapper PQAQ_wrapper_color" id="pbwidgetcontainer"><img id="loadingimg" '+'src="'+pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+'/images/app/qa/loading31.gif"></div><div id="PQAQ_customcss" class="PQAQ_customcss">'+'<style></style></div><div id="PQAQ_debug" class="PQAQ_debug"></div><div id="PQAQ_social" class="PQAQ_social"></div>  '+'     </div><div class="PQAM_footer_line"></div><div class="PQAM_footer"><div class="PQAM_poweredby PQAQ_pubble_logo" '+'id="PQAQ_logo_mb"></div><div class="PQAM_status"></div></div></div></div></div>'
}else{if(!c.qav3){tmpl='<div class="PQAQ_wrapper PQAQ_wrapper_color" id="pbwidgetcontainer"><img id="loadingimg" '+'style="width:31px !important" src="'+pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+'/images/app/qa/loading31.gif"></div><div id="PQAQ_customcss" '+'class="PQAQ_customcss"><style>.pb_highlight{opacity:0.5}</style></div><div id="PQAQ_social" class="PQAQ_social"></div>'+'<div id="PQAQ_debug" class="PQAQ_debug"></div>'}else{tmpl='<div class="PQAQ_modal_all PQAQ_off"><div class="PQAQ_modal"><div class="PQAQ_modal_close"></div><div class="PQAQ_modal_header"></div><div class="PQAQ_modal_content"> </div></div></div> <div class="PQAQ_wrapper PQAQ_wrapper_color" id="pbwidgetcontainer"><img id="loadingimg" '+'style="width:31px !important" src="'+pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+'/images/app/qa/loading31.gif"></div><div id="PQAQ_customcss" '+'class="PQAQ_customcss"><style>.pb_highlight{opacity:0.5}</style></div><div id="PQAQ_social" class="PQAQ_social"></div>'+'<div id="PQAQ_debug" class="PQAQ_debug"></div>'}}}}obj.innerHTML=tmpl;if(!c.qav4){if(c.qav3){initModule.loadLink("https://d2dfzm19238yrf.cloudfront.net/LQA/css/LQA_style.css")}else{initModule.loadLink("//www.pubble.io/resources/core/PQAB_style_v02.css")}if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf(" MSIE ")>-1){if(document.documentMode<9){c.theme="PQAM"}}if(c.theme=="PQAM"){initModule.loadLink(pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+"/qabuttons/css/template_metro.css")}else{if(c.theme=="PQAC"){initModule.loadLink(pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+"/qabuttons/css/template_classic.css")}else{initModule.loadLink(pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+"/qabuttons/css/template_modern.css")}}}var pusherLib=("https:"==document.location.protocol)?"https://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js":"http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js";DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(pusherLib,"utf-8");if(!c.qav4){if(pubbleLoader.utils.isMobile()&&!c.qav3){initModule.loadLink(pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+"/css/app/qa/PQAB_style_mobile.css","UTF-8")}if(c.layout=="modalbox"){initModule.loadLink(pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain+"/css/app/qa/PQAB_style_modal.css","UTF-8")}if(location.href.indexOf("facebook/qa")!==-1){c.scriptURL="//www.pubble.co/resources/javascript/widget/lib3.js"}}c.strings={};DynamicLoadScriptQueue.AddTask(c.scriptURL,"UTF-8");pubbleLoader.apps.push(c)}}}}};pubbleLoader.servers.cdnDomain=(("https:"==document.location.protocol)?"https://d2dfzm19238yrf.cloudfront.net":"https://d2dfzm19238yrf.cloudfront.net");window.pubbleLoader_init=true;return pubbleLoader})()}if(typeof(pubbleLoader)==="undefined"){pubbleLoader={}}if(typeof(pubbleLoader.config)==="undefined"){pubbleLoader.config={}}if(typeof(pubbleLoader.config.strings)==="undefined"){pubbleLoader.config.strings={}}if(typeof(pubbleLoader.init)==="undefined"){pubbleLoader.config={}}if(typeof(pubbleLoader.modules)==="undefined"){pubbleLoader.modules={}}pubbleLoader.views={};var DynamicLoadScriptQueue={Loading:false,TaskQueue:[],CallBack:function(StartTime,CallBackMethod){CallBackMethod&&CallBackMethod(new Date().valueOf()-StartTime.valueOf());this.Loading=false;this.Load()},Load:function(){var toLoad=false;toLoad=(!this.Loading&&this.TaskQueue.length);if(toLoad){var Head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];if(!Head){Head=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]}var DLSQ=this,TaskQueue=this.TaskQueue.shift(),StartTime=new Date;var Script;if(TaskQueue.href){Script=document.createElement("link")}else{Script=document.createElement("script")}this.Loading=true;Script.onload=Script.onreadystatechange=function(){if(Script&&Script.readyState&&Script.readyState!="loaded"&&Script.readyState!="complete"){return}Script.onload=Script.onreadystatechange=Script.onerror=null;DLSQ.CallBack(StartTime,TaskQueue.CallBackMethod);StartTime=TaskQueue=null};if(TaskQueue.href){Script.rel="stylesheet";Script.type="text/css";Script.href=TaskQueue.href;Script.media="all"}else{Script.src=TaskQueue.Src;Script.charset=TaskQueue.Charset||"utf-8"}var att=document.createAttribute("data");att.value="pb";Script.setAttributeNode(att);Head.appendChild(Script)}},AddTask:function(Src,Charset,CallBackMethod){if(Src.indexOf(".css")!=-1){this.TaskQueue.push({"href":Src,"rel":"stylesheet","type":"text/css","CallBackMethod":CallBackMethod})}else{this.TaskQueue.push({"Src":Src,"Charset":Charset,"CallBackMethod":CallBackMethod});this.Load()}}};pubbleLoader.utils={checkMetaView:function(){var metas=document.getElementsByTagName("meta");for(var i=0;i<metas.length;i++){if(metas[i].getAttribute("property")=="viewport"){return 1}}return 0},IE:function(){var trident=!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0/);var rv=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:11.0");var checked=false;var isIE=navigator.userAgent.indexOf(" MSIE ")>-1;if(isIE){checked=true}else{if(trident&&rv!=-1){checked=true}}return checked},Safari:function(){return/Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&/Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor)},Webkit:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/Webkit/i)},Android:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
},BlackBerry:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)},iOS:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)},iPad:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)},Opera:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i)},Windows:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)},any:function(){return(this.Android()||this.BlackBerry()||this.iOS()||this.Opera()||this.Windows())},isMobile:function(){var check=false;(function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|nexus|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iPad|ip(hone|od|pad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))){check=true}})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);return check},getQueryString:function(name){name=name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\]");var regexS="[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";var regex=new RegExp(regexS);var results=regex.exec(window.location.href);if(results==null){return null}else{return results[1]}},String:{toParams:function(obj){var ar=[];for(var x in obj){ar.push(x+"="+obj[x])}return ar.join("&")}},Url:{encode:function(a){return escape(this._utf8_encode(a))},decode:function(a){return this._utf8_decode(unescape(a))},_utf8_encode:function(b){b=b.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var a="";for(var e=0;e<b.length;e++){var d=b.charCodeAt(e);if(d<128){a+=String.fromCharCode(d)}else{if((d>127)&&(d<2048)){a+=String.fromCharCode((d>>6)|192);a+=String.fromCharCode((d&63)|128)}else{a+=String.fromCharCode((d>>12)|224);a+=String.fromCharCode(((d>>6)&63)|128);a+=String.fromCharCode((d&63)|128)}}}return a},_utf8_decode:function(a){var b="";var d=0;var e=c1=c2=0;while(d<a.length){e=a.charCodeAt(d);if(e<128){b+=String.fromCharCode(e);d++}else{if((e>191)&&(e<224)){c2=a.charCodeAt(d+1);b+=String.fromCharCode(((e&31)<<6)|(c2&63));d+=2}else{c2=a.charCodeAt(d+1);c3=a.charCodeAt(d+2);b+=String.fromCharCode(((e&15)<<12)|((c2&63)<<6)|(c3&63));d+=3}}}return b}}};if(pubbleLoader.utils.isMobile()){pubbleLoader.config.isMobile=1}if(window.pubbleApp_config){pubbleLoader(window.pubbleApp_config)}var pubbleLoader=pubbleLoader();function getElementsByClassName(className){var all=document.all?document.all:document.getElementsByTagName("*");var elements=new Array();for(var e=0;e<all.length;e++){if((all[e].className+"").indexOf(className)>-1){elements[elements.length]=all[e]}}return elements};
```

Comment: I don't think the referenced case was the same as yours, based on what you provided so far. In the referenced case the OP wanted to force a no-caching situation and needed to append a time-based unique value to the URL to fool the server into not caching. In your case...well you need to provided more details on what you have inside loader,js. Put another way, we need to see more of the code to be of any use.

Comment: ok - can't see anything relating to a new script declaration there. There must be something else going on. Are you sure it is the loader.js line that causes the error? Did you try removing it so confirm it is the cause? Are you confident that there is not an 'u[stream' script tag being opened but not closed when this code executes?

Comment: Yes the error is on the loader.js line. Not sure what you mean by  'u[stream' script tag being opened.

Comment: Apologies, typo - should have said 'upstream', meaning that there was an opening script tag somewhere earlier in the flow of code.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see for such error to occur is when you have such code:

```
<script runat="server">
    <div class="pubble-app PQAQ_section" data-app-id="43522"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.pubble.io/javascript/loader.js" defer></script>
</script>
```

While classic ASP runs server side and what you have is client side, such nesting is simply illegal. End the server side script tag before you have the client side script, and it should all work fine.